# insert query isn't working

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, sql-insert

[image]

```
INSERT INTO EmployeePrivileges (EmployeeID, PrivilegeID)
VALUES (
(SELECT ID
FROM Employees
WHERE Employees.JobTitle = 'Sales Manager'), 
(SELECT PrivilegeID
FROM Privileges
WHERE Privileges.PrivilegeName = 'Day opening and closing'));
```

I'm trying to run the above query in Ms Access but following error occurs
" error query input must contain at least one table or query" what to do?

Comment: My guess is your first query returns multiple rows (assuming your company has more than one Sales Manager).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used ms-access in some time, but as long as those 2 queries are just returning 1 row each you could combine them:

```
INSERT INTO EmployeePrivileges (EmployeeID, PrivilegeID)
    SELECT e.ID, p.PrivilegeID
     FROM Employees e, Privileges p
    WHERE e.JobTitle = 'Sales Manager'
      AND p.PrivilegeName = 'Day opening and closing';
```